# An excel cell need to be fixed, however the fixed cell should change, when i copy and the paste rows below

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have linked cells P11 to P17 with the cell E9 and formula for that I used is highlighted in image.

If I want make another control type, I will simply copy rows (8to17) and paste it in rows (19to28),

so in this case, do we have any formula, such a way that, the Type 1B should automatically referred and displayed in cells P22 to P27

Answer (score 0):

This formula would go in P11 and it assumes that the copy area is always 11 offset by 11 rows as your example suggests.

```
=INDEX(E:E,INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/11)*11+9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In P11, put :

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",P11),TRUE),-2,-11)
```

and in P12 put this and drag downwards... :

```
=P11
```

As for the 2nd set, 1st row (in P22) , just copy the 1st formula and paste. you should get :

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",P11),TRUE),-2,-11)
```

As for 2nd row (P23), do same as above).. put : `=P22` and drag downwards.

Idea : 1 cell 'defines' the reference, by a fixed offset, the rest refers top value.